# Laravel HasManyThrough doesn't work in this situation how to do it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

I have 3 models

User

- id

Event

- id
- end_time

EventUser (this represents a user who's joined an event with a comment)

- user_id
- event_id
- comment

We want to do `$user->events`
(to list the event details for all events user has joined)

But, as you can see, the intermediate table is a pivot table... therefore the events table does not reference it (which is the fourth parameter of the hasManyThrough function).

For example, I may want to get event **details** for all events a user has joined that has **ended.**

For now I am doing this in the User model

```
private function eventQuery() {
  return Event::join('event_user', 'events.id', '=', 'event_user.event_id')
         ->where('user_id', $this->id); // event_user.user_id
}

public function events() {
  return $this->eventQuery()->get();
}

public function pastEvents() {
  return $this->eventQuery()
         ->where('end_time', '<', new \DateTime()) // events.end_time
         ->get();
}
```

But is there a laravel way to do it like the hasManyThrough in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The laravel way is:

User Model:

```
public function events()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Event')->withPivot('comment');
}
```

Event Model:

```
public function users()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('comment');
}
```

When you do a call to:

```
$user = App\User::whereId($id)->where('end_time','<=',$now)->with('events')->get();
```

The events relation will be retrieved with the comment field of the pivot table, as you want it to be.